# will_paginate links past dataset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

It seems that in `will_paginate v3.1.6` after the end of the dataset, (say page 6) the next link is still clickable even though it shouldn't be.

[image]

To make matters worse chrome inspector shows that the disabled class is present. However an AJAX call gets through every time I click next even though the I have a "disabled" pointer.

[image]

Is this intentional?
Any ideas?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:
It turns out that by setting pointer-events in the disabled class we can get the expected behavior even though I am not certain that this is the proper way to do it.

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, no, just checked my links and they're not clickable when at the last page... It seems that somehow you've lost the ".disabled" class. You could do `<% if @model.total_pages == @model.current_page %>` and then use addClass "disabled"... But that's undesired...

Comment: Perhaps you already have ".disabled" class in your css that is overriding the will_paginate ".disabled"

Comment: @Crashtor I have updated my original post to provide more info.

Comment: You're right, it's not the proper way to do it. But if it works it works :) And it's not even a horrible solution.

Comment: For the record, I already opened a ticket https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/551. I'll update the post once someone comes back with a better solution.

Comment: Good to know! Cheers